# Check if post belongs to any category

Tags: plugin-development, categories

I've got a custom post type which displays portfolio items. I display the portfolio category on the page using this code:

```
<?php 
$myterms = get_the_terms($post->ID,'portfolio_category');
        foreach ($myterms as $myterm ) {
         echo $myterm->slug."\n";
        }   
    ?>
```

Which works fine as long as the portfolio item has a category. If it doesn't I get an error. Is there a way round this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`get_the_terms` return and error on failure. So before your foreach loop check for the error and only run it if there is none, using `is_wp_error`.

```
<?php 
$myterms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio_category' );

if( !is_wp_error( $myterms ) )
    foreach( $myterms as $myterm )
        echo $myterm->slug . '<br />';
?>
```

Comment: I really appreciate the response but I still get an error:  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()